# Jackson JSON processor problems

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have been scratching my head over this for hours now :

Jsckson  deserializes `B` but bombs on `C` below :

`B` and `C` are both subclasses of `A`, and thus has a setter `getName`.
Note that the uppercase `N` in `Name` is intentional, that is how my JSON looks.
Deserializing `C` complains about Unrecognized field name `Name`, for `B` it is OK.

Version 1.7.2

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(B.class, MixIn.class);
String json = "{\"Name\" : \"13\"}";
B b = m.readValue(json, B.class);
System.out.println(b.getName());
C c = m.readValue(json, C.class);
System.out.println(c.getName());
```

---

```
 public class A {
    private int id ;
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class B extends A {
private String address;

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
    }
}
```

---

```
 public class C extends A {
    private String country;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
 }
```

---

```
 @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE,setterVisibility=Visibility.ANY)
 abstract class MixIn  {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public abstract void setName(String name);

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public abstract void setId(int id);

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the default JSON field name to match a setter called `setName` is `name`, not `Name`. This is the Java property name convention.

The deserialization works for `B` because you've introduced the mixin that alters the field name that matches against `setName`.

Can't you just introduce the mixin for `C` also?

Answer (score 1):

You only added the name-uppercasing annotations to B.

```
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(B.class, MixIn.class);
```

To get C to work you need to do it for C as well.

```
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(C.class, MixIn.class);
```